# How to generate random samples from Gumbel’s bivariate exponential distribution?

Tags: random-generation, bivariate, exponential-distribution

The earliest and the simplest known bivariate exponential distribution, introduced by [Gumbel (1960)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2281591), has joint survivor function and joint probability density function given by:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:sf}
S(x, y) = \exp\left[- \left(\alpha\,x + \beta\,y + \theta\,\alpha\,\beta\,x\,y\right)\right]
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pdf}
f(x, y) = \left[(1 - \theta)\,\alpha\,\beta + \theta\,\alpha^2\,\beta\,x + \theta\,\alpha\,\beta^2\,y + 
\theta^2\,\alpha^2\,\beta^2\,x\,y\right]\,S(x, y)
\end{equation}
respectively, where $ x, y >0 $, $ \alpha, \beta \geq 0 $ and $ 0 < \theta < 1 $.

I want to generate random samples from this distribution. It is important to point out that the marginal distributions of X and Y are exponential with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the joint density\begin{equation}
f(x, y) = \left[(1 - \theta)\,\alpha\,\beta + \theta\,\alpha^2\,\beta\,x + \theta\,\alpha\,\beta^2\,y + 
\theta^2\,\alpha^2\,\beta^2\,x\,y\right]\,S(x, y)
\end{equation}
the conditional density of $Y$ given $X=x$ is such that
\begin{align}
f(y|x) &\propto \left[(1 - \theta)\,\alpha\,\beta + \theta\,\alpha^2\,\beta\,x\right]\, S(x, y)+ \left[\theta\,\alpha\,\beta^2 + 
\theta^2\,\alpha^2\,\beta^2\,x\right]\,y\,S(x, y)\\
&\propto \left[1 - \theta+ \theta\,\alpha x\right]\, S(x, y)+ \left[\theta + \theta^2\,\alpha\,\beta\,x\right]\,y\,S(x, y)\\
&\propto \left[1 - \theta+ \theta\,\alpha x\right]\, \exp\left[- \left(\beta\,y + \theta\,\alpha\,\beta\,x\,y\right)\right]+ \left[\theta + \theta^2\,\alpha\,\beta\,x\right]\,y\,\exp\left[- \left( \beta\,y + \theta\,\alpha\,\beta\,x\,y\right)\right]\\
&\propto \left[1 - \theta+ \theta\,\alpha x\right]\, \exp\left[- \beta\,y\left( 1+ \theta\,\alpha\,x\right)\right]+ \left[\theta + \theta^2\,\alpha\,\beta\,x\right]\,y\,\exp\left[- \beta\,y\left( 1 + \theta\,\alpha x \right)\right]\\\end{align}
which means that the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is a mixture of two distributions,

1. the exponential $\mathcal{E}(\beta\,\left\{ 1+ \theta\,\alpha\,x\right\})$ distribution
2. the Gamma $\mathcal{G}a(2,\beta\,\left\{ 1+ \theta\,\alpha\,x\right\})$ distribution

with respective weights $1$ and $$ \beta^{-1}\left[\theta + \theta^2\,\alpha\,\beta\,x\right]\times\left( 1 + \theta\,\alpha x \right)^{-2}$$up to normalisation. It is therefore straightforward to simulate $X$ marginally and then $Y$ given this realisation of $X$.